# How do I get multiple values from MySQL Relational Database tables using Ruby on Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, relational-database

I wasn't exactly sure how to word my question, so sorry if the question isn't phrased correctly.

Ill try to give the minimum amount of info needed to help me out. Please let me know edits to make or things to add. Thanks.

So I have a Relational MYSQL database already setup with data in 4 tables. This program is supposed to be a small-scale customer database lookup. I have an HTML page with a form: a text box asking for customer number, and 4 radio buttons to determine what data to retrieve. We're using Ruby on Rails (which I've never used) to access and control the data in the tables.

**The 4 radio buttons:**

- Customer Data
- Sales Rep
- Orders
- Parts

Here's a link to what these table's contain:  [http://www.cs.uky.edu/~paulp/CS316/tables.txt](http://www.cs.uky.edu/%7Epaulp/CS316/tables.txt)

The first two radio's were easy to implement since a **customerNum** is input. For customer data, I set variables to retrieve the values from the **customers** table. The **SalesRep** option was also easy. I took the **customerNum** input, set a variable to be the data in **customers** and another to be the data in **salesreps**. I made another variable to be the salesrep id by taking it from customers where **customerNum** was the input. Then used that sales rep id to display the associated data for the sales rep for that customer.

The 3rd and 4th radio options (orders and parts) has got me stumped! If you look at the orders table, some **customerNum**'s have multiple orders.

My question is essentially **"How do I go about displaying all of the orders (and the associated data for each) for a given customer?"**

I can't just do what I did for the first 2 radios since each **customerNum** could have 1 or multiple orders. I'm new to Ruby on Rails and not sure how to go about implementing this.

Ill post some code in a sec. Any suggestions to edits for this post or to help implement this are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

### CODE:

### index.html.erb

```
<%
#  index.html.erb
#  First (input) screen for example
%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>The Data Access Program</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Spartan Hardware Data Access</h1>
<form action="cs316ruby/result" method="post" >
<h3>Data requested:
<input type="text" name="data" /> </h3>
<ol>
  <li><input type="radio" name="field" value="cu" id="field_cu" checked="checked" />
    Customer data</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="field" value="sr" id="field_sr" />Sales rep</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="field" value="or" id="field_o" />Orders</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="field" value="p" id="field_p" />Parts</li>
</ol>
<input type="hidden" name=<%= request_forgery_protection_token.to_s %>
value=<%= form_authenticity_token %>  />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />      
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### salesrepdisplay.html.erb

```
<%
# salesrepisplay.html.erb.rb
# View that displays customer's sales rep data for cs316ruby program
%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>The Data Access Program</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Spartan Hardware Stores Data Access</h1>

  <%  # get the customer data from the customer table
  @custdata = Customer.find(@data)
  # copy the Sales rep field into a variable to retrieve sales rep data
  # if sales rep id = 00, the entered customer has no sales rep
  @sr = @custdata.sales_rep
  @srdata = Salesrep.find(@sr)
  @ln = @srdata.last_name
  @fn = @srdata.first_name
  @rt = @srdata.rate
  @cm = @srdata.commission;
  @cm = sprintf("%7.2f",@cm)
  %>
  <h1>Sales Rep data for customer: <%=@data %></h1>
  <table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Last name</td>
    <td>First name</td>
    <td>Commission</td>
    <td>Rate</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><%=@sr%></td>
    <td><%=@ln%></td>
    <td><%=@fn%></td>
    <td><%=@cm%></td>
    <td><%=@rt%></td>
  </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

### custdisplay.html.erb

```
<%
# custdisplay.html.erb.rb
# View that displays customer data for cs316ruby program
%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<title>The Data Access Program</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Spartan Hardware Stores Data Access</h1> 
 <%  # get the customer data from the customer table
 @custdata = Customer.find(@data)
 # copy each field into a variable for display
 @id = @custdata.id
 @ln = @custdata.last_name
 @fn = @custdata.first_name
 @bl = @custdata.balance;
 @bl = sprintf("%7.2f",@bl) # format as currency
 @cl = @custdata.credit_limit
 @cl = sprintf("%7.2f",@cl) # format as currency
 @sr = @custdata.sales_rep
 %>
 <h1>customer data for customer: <%=@data %></h1>
 <table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Last name</td>
    <td>First name</td>
    <td>Balance</td>
    <td>Credit limit</td>
    <td>Sales rep</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><%=@id%></td>
    <td><%=@ln%></td>
    <td><%=@fn%></td>
    <td><%=@bl%></td>
    <td><%=@cl%></td>
    <td><%=@sr%></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

### orderdisplay.html.erb

**This is basically a copy and paste of the sales rep and customer order pages to start from**

```
<%
# orderdisplay.html.erb
# View that displays customer's order data for cs316ruby program
%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<title>The Data Access Program</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Spartan Hardware Stores Data Access</h1>

<%  # get the customer data from the customer table
@custdata = Customer.find(@data)
%>
<h1>Order data for customer: <%=@data %></h1>
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>Order Number</td>
    <td>Order Date</td>
    <td>Cost of Order</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><%=@sr%></td>
    <td><%=@ln%></td>
    <td><%=@fn%></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

Comment: You will next need `<% @custdata.orders.each do |order| %>`. And that will require `Customer.has_many :orders` in your models. Then put the order data into each `<tr>` (and drop the excess `@` that you don't need), and close the `each` loop with a <% end %>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

I was close to figuring it out one way with the code I had. Here's the code block that put everything into an array, then the loop to access values each iteration:

```
<% #creating the array
    @orderdata = Order.find(:all, :conditions => ["customer_ID = ?",@data])


#the loop
 @custdata.orders.each do |order| 

   @id = order.id %>

     <td><%=@id%></td>

<%end%>
```

So much easier than I thought it would be!

Comment: "So much easier than I thought it would be!"? Welcome to Ruby on Rails!

Comment: Thanks haha. Yeah I way over complicated it and once I understood how some of the methods worked, it all clicked!

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask a narrower question. (Also ~'s is possessive; plain ~s is for plurals.)

Reviewing your tables.txt, orderlines.id appears to mean orderline.order_id - that is the foreign key of orders, in orderlines.

So if you expressed these as ActiveRecord objects, how would you write in `class Order` a has_many that points to `OrderLine`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Like I said, I've never used RoR before this project :/ I'll try to revise my question too^

Comment: Try literally reading a book on RoR, from the beginning, just to make this stuff sink in.

Comment: Yeah I'm doing tons of beginner tutorials lol but everything is presented in a way that doesn't seem relative to what I need so far

Comment: You are writing PHP Classic style Rails... C-;